# Largest decidable subsystem of Robinson's arithmetic $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: decidability

What is the largest decidable subsystem of  $\mathbb{Q}$? Is there any nice axiomatization of it known?

Edit: Given Noah Schweber's comment, let me rephrase the question, why is there no largest decidable subsystem of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the situation is even worse than my comment suggests:

### $Q$ has **no decidable subtheories at all!**

First, let's fix a couple definitions for explicitness:

- A *theory* will mean any set of sentences which is consistent.

  - Most texts don't require consistency, and some texts do require deductive closure *(in the jargon to be introduced below: that $T=Thm(T)$)*. But I think this definition is the best for the current situation.
- When we say that a theory $T$ is *decidable*, we mean that the set of theorems of $T$ $$Thm(T):=\{\varphi: T\vdash\varphi\}$$ (also called the *deductive closure* of $T$) is computable.

  - It's worth noting that in computability theory, when talking about a general set of natural numbers *(or things "morally equivalent" to such, like sentences via Godel numbering)*, the words "decidable," "computable," and "recursive" are all synonyms. **We're really bad at terminology, y'all.**

The key point now is the following:

> **Lemma**: Suppose $T_0\subseteq T_1$ are theories, $T_1$ is finitely axiomatizable over $T_0$ *(= there is some single sentence $\varphi$ such that $Thm(T_1)=Thm(T_0\cup\{\varphi\})$)*, and $T_1$ is undecidable. Then $T_0$ is also undecidable.

*Proof*: [We have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) $$\psi\in Thm(T_1)\quad\iff\quad \varphi\rightarrow\psi\in Thm(T_0)$$ for every sentence $\psi$. So if we could compute $Thm(T_0)$ we could compute $Thm(T_1)$. $\quad\Box$

> **Corollary**: No subset of $Q$ is decidable.

*Proof*: $Q$ is finitely axiomatizable, hence is finitely axiomatizable over all its subsets, and is undecidable. Now apply the lemma. $\quad\Box$

On that note, it's worth observing that smaller theories aren't necessarily simpler: [Presburger arithmetic](http://www.lsv.fr/~haase/documents/h18.pdf) is decidable, but the empty theory in the same language *isn't*. Adding more axioms sometimes results in more simplicity by ruling out those possibilities which could lead to complexity.

---

There's a related, slightly less trivial, situation which is also worth understanding: that of *computably enumerable sets*. Sets of the form $Thm(T)$ for $T$ a computable theory are c.e., but not all c.e. sets "look like" this, and indeed we can have much more variety in general c.e. sets:

> **Lemma**: If $X$ is c.e. and infinite then $X$ has an infinite computable subset. (In particular, since any finite set is computable, every c.e. but non-computable set has an infinite computable subset.)

*Proof*: Since $X$ is c.e. we have $X=ran(f)$ for some (total) computable function $f$. Now the computable sequence $$f(0),f(1),f(2),...$$ need not enumerate $X$ in order, but we can extract an increasing subsequence computably: we define by recursion

- $s_0=0$,
- $s_{i+1}=\min\{s>s_i: f(s)>f(s_i)\}$,

and let $a_i=f(s_i)$. Then $$a_0,a_1,a_2,...$$ is a computable increasing sequence, and so the set $$A=\{a_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ is computable - we have $$n\in A\iff n=a_0\mbox{ or }n=a_1\mbox{ or } ...\mbox{ or }n=a_n,$$ the point being that since the sequence of $a$s is increasing we know when to stop searching. Meanwhile, clearly $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$, so we're done. $\quad\Box$

*Incidentally, note that this $A$ depends on $f$; there are many $f$s corresponding to a given $X$, so we do not have a "canonical" computable subset of $X$ in any sense.*

So for general c.e. sets the situation is more interesting than for sentences, at least as far as the OP is concerned. Despite this we *still* never have maximal computable subsets:

> Suppose $X$ is a c.e. set which is not computable. Then $X$ has no largest computable subset.

*Proof*: Suppose $C\subseteq X$ is computable. Since $X$ isn't computable, we have $C\subsetneq X$. Let $a\in X\setminus C$; then $C\cup\{a\}$ is also computable (adding one element to a computable set leaeves it computable), is a subset of $X$, and is a proper superset of $C$. $\quad\Box$