# How long can proofs be?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, provability

Let 
$$f(n) = \max\{\text{length of shortest proof of }\varphi \mid \varphi \text{ is a provable ZFC sentence of length } \leq n\}$$

How fast does $f$ grow? Is it polynomial, exponential, more than exponential, etc.?

Comment: I appear to have been out-sped :P But I'll remark here what I would have put at the end of my answer: the function you're describing is related to the [busy beaver function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), and because busy beavers are taught in a lot of CS classes, you will probably have more luck googling for it, even if it isn't on-the-nose what you're interested in.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This function grows **really** fast: there is no computable function which bounds it!

To see this, note that if we had a computable bound on $f$ we could tell whether a sentence $\sigma$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (just search over all proofs of length $<f(\vert\sigma\vert+1)$ for a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of $\neg\sigma$). But from this information we could in turn build a computable complete consistent extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$:

- Fix an appropriate enumeration $(\sigma_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the sentences in the language of set theory.
- Define a new sequence $(\tau_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of sentences by recursion as follows:

  - $\tau_0=\sigma_0$ if $\sigma_0$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and $\tau_0=\neg\sigma_0$ otherwise.
  - $\tau_{i+1}=\sigma_{i+1}$ if $\sigma_{i+1}\wedge\bigwedge_{j\le i}\tau_i$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and $\tau_{i+1}=\neg\sigma_{i+1}$ otherwise.
- The set $\{\tau_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is then a complete computable consistent theory containing $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (note that when $\sigma_i$ is an axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we'll have $\tau_i=\sigma_i$).

However, this contradicts the first incompleteness theorem. (Or Church's theorem, if you like - basically the above is the proof of Church's theorem from the first incompleteness theorem.)

---

Note that we really used very little about $\mathsf{ZFC}$ here. The first incompleteness theorem applies to a *huge* range of theories, ranging from much weaker than $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to much stronger than $\mathsf{ZFC}$; briefly, any consistent computably axiomatizable theory which satisfies a very mild technical "strength condition" (basically: at least as powerful as [Robinson's $Q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic)) is subject to this phenomenon. See section $4$ of [this paper of Beklemishev](http://www.mi-ras.ru/~bekl/Papers/goedel-en.pdf) for more details on this point.

*To be precise, the form of the first incompleteness theorem I'm using is: "Every computably axiomatizable consistent theory which interprets Robinson's $\mathsf{Q}$ is incomplete." Note that we don't need an $\omega$-consistency assumption here; while present in Godel's original proof, it was [later removed by Rosser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick).*

Comment: It may be useful for the  OP note explicitly that the first two sentences of this answer (with $f(|\sigma|+1)$ because $\neg\sigma$ is one symbol longer than $\sigma$) answer the question not only for ZFC but for any undecidable but computably axiomatizable theory. Examples range from Robinson's Q up to ZFC plus any large cardinal axiom that's consistent with ZFC.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Edited, thanks!

Comment: Hmm why don't you just say that you can computably decide whether a sentence over ZFC is a theorem or not? Saves the trouble of building a computable complete extension. =)

Comment: @user21820 That's what I was thinking -- isn't it a theorem of Church's that every recursively axiomatizable theory in the language of arithmetic that is consistent with Robinson arithmetic is undecidable? That's immediately contradicted above if we note that Robinson arithmetic can be easily interpreted in PA (and hence ZFC, ZFC + Con(ZFC), etc.).

Comment: @MacRance: Yes see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486348/21820) for an easy reduction to what I called the zero-guessing problem (which is weaker than the halting problem and yields the stronger incompleteness theorem).

Comment: Can you please add the last step of the proof, which is (as far as I understand this proof) that this construction is in contradiction to the incompleteness theorem? I feel like this closes the proof but is left more or less implicit here.

Comment: @MacRance I wasn't using Church's theorem since in my experience it's less well-known. The argument I wrote out basically is the proof of Church's theorem.

Comment: @kutschkem Ask and ye shall receive!

Comment: As an outsider to this field, I have a potentially very naive question: it seems to me that this construction only proves that "it is not provable that $f$ is bounded by any computable function." It doesn't prove that it grows faster than all of them. If it is unprovable that $f$ is bounded by (e.g.) an exponential, that doesn't mean it grows faster than exponential. Am I right?

Comment: @stochastic No, that's not right: $f$ genuinely can't be bounded by any computable function. The point is that Godel's theorem rules out the existence of a computable consistent completion of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, full stop, not just a "provable" computable consistent completion. If $f$ is bounded by a computable function, then we can whip up a computable consistent completion of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The provability of $f$ being bounded by a computable function isn't relevant to this.

Comment: This can perhaps more clearly be phrased as the observation that "$f$ is bounded by some computable function $h$" implies "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a computable consistent completion," and "$f$ is provably bounded by some computable function $h$" implies "There is a specific theory $T$ which we can prove is a computable consistent completion of $\mathsf{ZFC}$." While the second conclusion is stronger, Godel already rules out the first conclusion: it's an outright nonexistence result.

Comment: @MacRance Is Presburger arithmetic not a decidable recursively axiomatizable theory in the language of arithmetic that is consistent with Robinson arithmetic?

Comment: @user76284 No, it's not in the language of arithmetic - it doesn't include a symbol for multiplication. Precisely: the *minimal language* for Presburger arithmetic is not the language of arithmetic, and Presburger arithmetic is only decidable in the context of its *minimal language*. Note that this highlights an annoying abuse of terminology, namely that when we say "$T$ is decidable" what we actually mean is "The set of theorems of $T$ *in the minimal language for $T$* is decidable" - I discussed this in more detail in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387027/28111).