# Theorems that won't be proved by a computer

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, philosophy

I want to prove in the following way there is a statement that a computer can't prove. Suppose the time of life of our universe is limited by $t$ and the speed of calculations is limited by $s$. Now, consider the axioms of Peano arithmetic (PA). Can we show that for a given $n$ (in particular, $n=ts$), there is a sentence $S(n)$ provable in PA, such that the minimal number of strings in a (Hilbert-style) proof of $S(n)$ is greater than $n$?

Comment: Ask the computer to find a nontrivial integer solution to $x^n+y^n=z^n$ for all $n\ge 3$. There are infinitely many $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Godel's incompleteness theorem gives you a stronger result: if you have a computer program that only outputs true statements about natural numbers, then there is a true statement about natural numbers that your program will *never* output. And if you have one unprovable statement, you can get infinitely many more by taking its conjunction with other provable statements.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "shortest form"? When are two forms considered equivalent?

Comment: @Karl I've tried to consider FOL-sentences, then we mean they are equivalent (in terms of FOL including all possible interpretations)...

Comment: Hmm, would you consider $s$ to be proved if $s$ and $t$ are equivalent and you have a proof of $t$ but not a proof that $s$ and $t$ are equivalent?

Comment: Have a look at the [proof sketch for Gödel's first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_sketch_for_G%C3%B6del%27s_first_incompleteness_theorem). In this Wikipedia article, the formula $P(G(P))$ is an explicit example for exactly the kind of unprovable statement you are looking for. This construction works for every system of axioms that can describe the Peano arithmetic.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for this link (I really need to study it), but I mean more the existence of sentences which can be proven but their minimal length is sufficiently large... Also (but this is another question), I am interested in "lower bounds" of the length of a proof.

Comment: See e.g. [how long can proofs be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671456/how-long-can-proofs-be)

Comment: If you're just looking for very long statements, try things like "$1\ldots 1 + 1\ldots 1 = 2\ldots 2$".

Comment: Once again, Gödel to the rescue, he did a lot to answer these kinds of questions :D See [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/#SpeUpThe): "Theorem 5: Given any recursive function f there are provable sentences φ of arithmetic such that the shortest proof is greater than f(⌈φ⌉) in length". And, in general, see the description of [Gödel's speed-up theorem on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_speed-up_theorem).

Comment: @Karl I've totally edited the question. Now, it's indeed more about the proof's length :-)

Comment: This may appear to be an off-topic comment (but it bears on the mathematical facts that are relevant to you, so I think it is really on-topic). You want to show that "there is a statement that a computer can't prove" based on physical limitations for computation in a universe that is postulated to be finite. Are you requiring the statement to be physically realisable in some way but that the proof is not physically? If so, what you are looking for sounds like a delicate balancing act.

Comment: There are infinitely many provable statements, only finitely many proofs with length at most $n$, and each proof proves at most one statement, so there is definitely a statement that has a proof but all its proves have length more than $n$.

Comment: @RobArthan thanks for your comment! I agree there is a kind of uncertainty (which may be due to the relativity of a human's knowledge). I just try to define the computational limitations, understanding this definition is fully conditional. In some sense, I even say that, in spite a computer can prove a sentence, we do not accept this proof untill it is not short enough...

Comment: @mihaild your argument is really elegant!

Comment: You can't prove a statement without writing it out, so mihaild's argument follows from the even simpler fact that there are arbitrarily long provable *statements*, such as those suggested by Robert Israel ($1+\dots+1=\dots$). If you want to exclude these boring cases, you need to look for long proofs of *short* statements, as Rob Arthan suggests. This is where the proof length function in [how long can proofs be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671456/how-long-can-proofs-be) comes in. I think that post answers your question.

Comment: You actually could prove statements without writing them down if you used a calculus of proof terms with proposition inference analogous to Hindley-Milner. Then, there are proof terms whose 'principal proposition' has size $O(2^{2^n})$, where $n$ is the size of the proof term. The usual examples are also not interesting, though. They look like $P → P ∧ P$, $P → (P ∧ P) ∧ (P ∧ P)$ and so on (at each step, replace each $P$ in the consequent with the entire consequent).

Comment: @DanDoel I think the similar idea is as follows. Consider the generative grammar with two inference rules $S\rightarrow aS$ and $S\rightarrow e$. We can easily prove by induction that this grammar produces any word $a^n$. Now, interprete such words as theorems and sequences of rules (like 1112) as proofs. Then there is a theorem with its proof which has a prescribed (minimal) length, but we know about this fact implicitly,
reasoning in an outer formal system by induction.