# Classifying all vacuously true FOL statements in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

Although [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) stands tall as the standard set theory, there is no shortage of [alternative set theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_set_theory#:%7E:text=In%20a%20general%20sense%2C%20an,of%20Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel%20set%20theory). Many of which differ on fundamental theories. This has me wondering, assuming first order logic (FOL),

> What statements are true within all set theories?

Or in other words,

> Which FOL statements are vacuously true, assuming no axioms?

---

**My work:** Initially, I thought this was a trivial problem, as for any vacuously true zeroth-order logic statement, like $\phi\implies \phi$, we can substitute $\phi\mapsto a\in a$, (since the atoms of FOL set theory are of the form $x \in y$), then append a universal quantifier such as
$$\forall a(a\in a\implies a\in a),$$

and we get a vacuously true statement. I'll call these types of vacuously true statements the "trivial" ones, as it wasn't long before I realized there were less obvious FOL statements which must be vacuously true and are not constructed in this way. A prime example is the statement
$$\forall x \exists y(y\in x \iff y\in y).$$
This must be vacuously true, as if it weren't, Russell's Paradox ensues. We can classify these types of non-trivials as follows:

For any condition $\phi(x,w_1,\cdots,w_n)$ which fails as a zeroeth order logic statement if all arguments are the same (i.e; $\neg\phi(x,x,\cdots,x)$) then the statement
$$\forall x\exists w_1\cdots \exists w_n[\neg\phi(x,w_1,\cdots,w_n)]$$
is vacuously true. For example, taking $\phi(x,y)\equiv y\in x\iff x\notin x$, as in the example of Russell's Paradox, fails when $x=y$.

> Are these the only two methods of producing vacuously true FOL statements of set theory, or are there more?

> If so, what is the best way to classify them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually as complicated as it's possible to be. For any pair of sentences $\theta,\varphi$ in the language of set theory, we have that $\theta\rightarrow\varphi$ is a tautology (= provable without using any axioms at all) iff $\theta\vdash\varphi$. But there are quite complicated finitely-axiomatizable theories in the language $\{\in\}$!

In particular, let $T$ be a "large enough" finite subtheory of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Then we can let $\theta$ be the conjunction of all the axioms of $T$, and the set of set-theoretic tautologies is then at least as complicated as the set of theorems of $T$ - which, since $T$ is "large enough," is as complicated as it could possibly be (namely as complicated as the halting problem).

(As a tangential coda, note that the above fact is related to the fact that, for example, $\mathsf{Q}$ has no decidable subtheories - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386222/largest-decidable-subsystem-of-robinsons-arithmetic-mathbbq/3387027#3387027).)

Comment: That is truly fascinating. Do you know of any resources, or related searchable keywords, which study this sort of thing? I am quite curious of what can be known about axiom-less-theories, particular of set theory.